# How to make Beyond Compare work within Eclipse with Git?

Tags: java, eclipse, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

There is clear explanation how to make BC a default tool for diff and merging for Subversion and Git when used *not* from within Eclipse. But what about the latter? I keep getting the following dialog:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Added to my global .gitconfig and `git difftool` command now works. Can't say the same about Eclipse. I can't get why it's so confusing to set up.

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "bc3"]
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.exe\" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

My Eclipse config now looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=11753) suggests:

- tinkering the the git config

  > Eclipse Preferences, under `Team -> Git -> Configuration`, it points to a `.gitconfig` file. (and [declare beyond compare as documented](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitwindows))
- or... Use Intellij IDEA(!)

The integration of Beyond Compare and Eclipse itself is based on a plugin, so a *direct* integration between BC and EGit might not be possible directly through Eclipse.

Comment: Not exactly that but the other SO thread helped. The BC docs are useless for some reason. See edited post for what I have ended up adding.

Comment: I am doing Google App Engine development so I need to investigate if Google provides the same dev infrastructure for Intellij.

Comment: @Schultz9999 Excellent. That is why I referenced that SO post.

Comment: Well, Eclipse still won't work so it's still pain in neck to do diff because Java paths are SO long and it's take forever to get to a file in cmd line to run `git difftool filename`. The only way to save time is just run without file specs but then it diffs all changed files... Just pain. I don't understand why BC team wouldn't help.

Comment: @Schultz9999 I agree, this is a workaround at best. BC team might no be willing to invest in the development of a full-fledged eclipse plugin right now.

Comment: from command line adding -d like "git difftool -d" you can compare the whole folder structures.

Comment: @BradGReynolds I agree. The question being for Eclipse, I did not consider that alternative (since Eclipse with Git does not mean you have a Git CLI installed). For more on `git difftool -d`, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739808/6309).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old thread, but appears to have a new answer.
The [BC thread](http://hhttps://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/forum/beyond-compare-3-discussion/version-control/9412-integerate-with-eclipse-egit?t=11753) mentioned above had a fairly new entry mentioning [Context Quickie](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/contextquickie).  I installed that, configured it to use BC 4 in my case, and have a much more readable compare when in egit.