# Add external comparison tool in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, beyondcompare

I have been trying to add BeyondCompare as my code compare tool in Eclipse but couldn't find a way to do so.

I am using Eclipse Mars version and when I searched on Google , some solutions were there but that options are not there in updated version now.

Can someone please help me in doing it as it's very hard to understand differences in Eclipse comparison tool.

I don't think there is any post related to this , so guys please reply.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Which links did you read, and in which way do things "not work"?

Comment: Add the links that you have tried

Comment: Have you tried Beyond CVS plugin? http://beyondcvs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Are you using Eclipse on Windows, macOS, or Linux? Are you using Git as your version control system? Usually external diff and merge tools are configured separately for each version control plugin in the **Team** section of Eclipse's **Windows > Preferences** dialog.

Comment: @chris kennedy - I am using Eclipse on windows and yes I am using GIT as my version control tool.I have seen that there is some option in Team section in preferences but in Ecplise Mars version , it is not there.

Comment: @ P.An - I downloaded the beyond CVS plugin and unzipped it.Now how can I import it in Eclipse.

Comment: I even got a similar thread which has same question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507729/how-to-make-beyond-compare-work-within-eclipse-with-git

Comment: It appears development on the Beyond CVS plugin has stopped. The last release was in 2010, so it might not work with newer versions of Eclipse.